# peagsus time attendance Machine SDK required to integrate peagsus device

Tags: c#-4.0, sdk

I want to develop time attendance management system so have to integrate the fingerprint device  could anyone help me where can i get the sdk of the device

Comment: Ask your hardware provider fri sdk.

Comment: Ask you hardware vendor